# RSS Statistics/Traffic Metrics

Tags: rss, metrics

I want to track how much traffic I'm getting on an RSS feed that is set up using .Net 2.0 & SQL Server.

Is there an industry standard on what metrics I should use, for example, page hits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feedburner analysis gives you statistics like:
[image]
<sub>(source: [blogperfume.com](http://www.blogperfume.com/feed-analysis/feed-analysis1.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [blogperfume.com](http://www.blogperfume.com/feed-analysis/feed-analysis2.png))</sub>
[image]
<sub>(source: [blogperfume.com](http://www.blogperfume.com/feed-analysis/feed-analysis3.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I agree, FeedBurner is probably your best option, almost all large sites use it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tracking it yourself, I would encourage you to use a service like [FeedBurner](http://www.feedburner.com/). Even if you don't want to use a 3rd party service it will give you an idea of what other people track for RSS feeds.